# Getting "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" error in chrome with extjs 6

Tags: forms, google-chrome, extjs6-modern

Created a form in extjs-6 - modern for file upload.
After new update on chrome browser i am getting following error "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

I tried with rendering the form on body also, still getting the same error.
Please suggest anything i am missing.Thanks in advance.

```
Ext.define('LayersSurvey.view.Attachments', 
{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.attachments',
    controller: 'Basecontrol',
    closeAction: 'hide',
    closable: false,
    colapsible: true,
    //zIndex: 9999,
    scrollable: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    multipartDetection:true,
    items:
    [{
        xtype: 'selectfield',       
        label: 'Floor',
        labelAlign: 'left',
        //labelWidth :'30%',
        name: 'attachmentType',
        required: true,
        options: 
        [{
            text: 'G-2',
            value: '-2'
        }, {
            text: 'G-1',
            value: '-1'
        },{
            text: 'G',
            value: '0'
        }, {
            text: 'M',
            value: '0.5'
        },{
            text: 'G+1',
            value: '1'
        }, {
            text: 'G+2',
            value: '2'
        },{
            text: 'G+3',
            value: '3'
        }, {
            text: 'G+4',
            value: '4'
        },{
            text: 'G+5',
            value: '5'
        }, {
            text: 'G+6',
            value: '6'
        },{
            text: 'G+7',
            value: '7'
        },{
            text: 'G+8',
            value: '8'
        },{
            text: 'G+9',
            value: '9'
        },{
            text: 'G+10',
            value: '10'
        }],
        listeners:
        {

        }
    },{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        //label: "Attachment:",
        name: 'photo',
        //bodyAlign:'center',
        accept: 'image',
        listeners: 
        {
            tap:'onMediaChange'
        }
    },
    {
        xtype:'button',
        text: 'Upload',
        ui: 'action',
        action:'',
        listeners: {tap:'onMediaUpload'}

    }]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In the config for your form, make sure `enableSubmissionForm` is set to false.

In the case where I had this issue, I was using Architect to create the web app version of my app, and in Chrome I was getting the same error.  By default, `enableSubmissionForm` seems to be `true` in extjs 6.x modern.